# Should the neutral be hot for my stove wiring?

Tags: electrical

Existing wiring is 1 red hot 1 black hot each coming into a 20 A breaker. Box has no ground. Is the neutral on this needing to be hot or do I have to run a whole new wire to new box with a ground & keep the neutral, neutral?

[image]

Picture: New wire harness
[image]

Comment: Picture of the open box? You may have a ground you don't recognize (such as via metallic conduit.) If this global appliance is listed for (presumably North America given red and black hot) then line is hot and neutral is the other hot for this locale. But ground is ground and you need that.

Comment: Your general location is needed.  Those colours seem to European where black/red are more American.  Mixing an appliance of one with the power system of the other, requires more information.

Comment: How do you know that the third wire isn't a ground?  (That label on the bottom wire looks like ground to me.)

Comment: If this is in an older English/European house that black/red wires might work.  I think this was the old colour scheme with black meaning/used as neutral and red for power.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the wall please?

Comment: Can you post the name plate for the stovetop?

Comment: What country are you in? Did you buy this cheap via mail-order?

Comment: What does "20 amp each" mean? Each what? And where is that info coming from? Red and black wires entering a box in the U.S. would indicate a 240V supply, with no neutral involved.

Comment: Arizona, USA. Wiring was done in the 60s. The box is not good, too old & needs replacing. I put solar in the other year, so the outside main has a ground. I'll probably need to just run a new wire

Comment: Hey, hey! You've got one of those bright & cheerful Zinsco fire-starter panels. Yeah, no kidding that box needs to be replaced. That should be your #1 priority before trying to hook up this stove to that panel.

Answer (score 2):

### I don't care where that stove from, it's not being properly protected against overcurrent anyway, because uh-oh! You have a Zinsco!

Your Zinsco panel and breakers [cannot provide proper overcurrent protection to anything](https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Zinsco_Summary.htm), no matter who did or didn't test or list the appliance, so I'd replace that panel first, *then* go shopping at a reputable bricks-and-mortar outlet for a new cooktop, as trying to do much of anything to a circuit "protected" by a Zinsco breaker is a bad idea -- they can't even be counted on to turn the power off when you switch them off!  (Generally speaking, cooktops and non-cord-connected ranges made for the North American market will use a flexible conduit instead of a cord or tray-cable for the hardwiring whip.)

Once that's done, post a new question with photos of the box in the wall where the range circuit terminates, and *then* we can talk about retrofitting a grounding wire to this circuit if need be.  (The red/black wire pair makes me suspect this circuit might have been run in conduit.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in the US, but your stove has a European style cord.

If the stove was used on a European style supply, then the L would indeed be connected to the Hot and the N to the neutral.

However, if you do that on a typical north American supply then your stove will almost certainly not get enough voltage. Most likely you will need to connect the "L" to one hot and the "N" to the other hot to get the correct voltage. This is generally safe as European/IEC appliance design practice treats the "Neutral" as being potentially live.

Ideally the manufacturer would document this sort of thing but...........

In any case ground needs to be connected to the ground connection.

Either way the ground needs to be connected

Answer (score -2):

That's a standard European single phase cable.  One live/hot (L), one neutral (N), and one ground/earth.  They have even helpfully labelled them for you.

Since the cable has a ground wire, it must be connected, so you need to work out where to get the ground from.